# How to Add +1 day if shipout day is Sunday?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

How to add +1 if the shipout from or to day is SUNDAY?

```
<div class="shipout">
<p id="postage">Postage: <span id="postage-msg">FREE (UK MAINLAND)</span></p>
<span id="shipout-title"></span><span id="shipout-date"></span>
<script>
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  locale = "en-us";
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  var curr_date = dat.getDate();
  var s=["th","st","nd","rd"];
  v= curr_date %100;
  var curr_month = dat.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
  return curr_date + (s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]) + " " + curr_month + " " + "(" + ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'][dat.getDay()] +")";
}

var dat = new Date();

document.getElementById("shipout-title").innerHTML = "Estimated Delivery: "
document.getElementById("shipout-date").innerHTML =  dat.addDays(4) + " - " + dat.addDays(5)

</script>
</div>
```

As of current Script the Output will be `Estimated Delivery: 25th March (Sat) - 26th March (Sun)` If today is 21st March Tuesday.

I need the output like `Estimated Delivery: 25th March (Sat) - 27th March (Mon)` If today is 21st March Tuesday.

Also

As of current Script the Output will be `Estimated Delivery: 26th March (Sun) - 27th March (Mon)` If today is 22nd March Wednesday.

I need the output like `Estimated Delivery: 27th March (Mon) - 28th March (Tue)` If today is 22nd March Wednesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code to remove Sunday from Days.

```
    <div class="shipout">
<p id="postage">Postage: <span id="postage-msg">FREE (UK MAINLAND)</span></p>
<span id="shipout-title"></span><span id="shipout-date"></span>
<script>
var flag = false;;
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  if(flag == true){
    days = days + 1;
    flag = false;
  }
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  locale = "en-us";
  dat.setDate(24 + days);
  var curr_date = dat.getDate();

//Changes Start
  var day = dat.getDay();
  if(dat.toLocaleString(locale, { weekday: "long" }) == 'Sunday'){
    curr_date = dat.getDate() + 1;
    day = day + 1;
    flag = true;
  }

//Changes End
  var s=["th","st","nd","rd"];
  v= curr_date %100;

  var curr_month = dat.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
  return curr_date + (s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]) + " " + curr_month + " " + "(" + ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'][day] +")";
}

var dat = new Date();

document.getElementById("shipout-title").innerHTML = "Estimated Delivery: "
document.getElementById("shipout-date").innerHTML =  dat.addDays(2) + " - " + dat.addDays(3)

</script>
</div>
```

I Updated my code. Hope it helps.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code. but it will be "Estimated Delivery: 27th March (Mon) - 27th March (Mon)" if today is 25th and "document.getElementById("shipout-date").innerHTML =  dat.addDays(2) + " - " + dat.addDays(3)"

Comment: is showing me 27th and 28th if today's date is 25th. working fine for me. Check attached screen shot in my answer. Clear cache and check it again. Try your code here.  https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_setdate

Comment: Posted script and the shared image has different scripts. image has dat.setDate(25 + days); instead of "dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);"

Comment: I have edited my question. Updated the line "document.getElementById("shipout-date").innerHTML =  dat.addDays(4) + " - " + dat.addDays(5)"

Comment: Image script is different just because to get 25th date as you requested for 2nd(27 march) and 3rd(28 day) day.

Comment: I see but the output is wrong for the live script. plz check with current script. dat.addDays(ADD OR REDRUCE DAYS HERE)

Comment: I update my code. please check it.